# difference in two date column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, date-difference

I am trying to get difference between two date columns below script and data used in script, but I am getting same results for all three rows

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Book1.csv',encoding='cp1252')
df
Out[36]: 
              Start              End  DifferenceinDays  DifferenceinHrs
0  10/26/2013 12:43  12/15/2014 0:04               409             9816
1    2/3/2014 12:43   3/25/2015 0:04               412             9888
2   5/14/2014 12:43    7/3/2015 0:04               409             9816
```

I am expecting results as in column DifferenceinDays which is calculated in excel but in python getting same values for all three rows, Please refer to below code used, can anyone let me know how is to calculate difference between 2 date column, I am trying to get number of hours between two date columns.

```
df["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df["End"] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])

df['hrs']=(df.End-df.Start)
df['hrs']
Out[38]: 
0   414 days 11:21:00
1   414 days 11:21:00
2   414 days 11:21:00
Name: hrs, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I think output is correct, there is same difference in 3 rows of data

Comment: @jazrael, My bad you are absolutely correct, yes difference is exactly same

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `np.timedelta64(1,'h')`

Additionally, it looks like excel calculates the hours differently, unsure why.

```
import numpy as np
df['hrs'] = (df['End'] - df['Start']) / np.timedelta64(1,'h')

print(df)

                Start                 End  DifferenceinHrs      hrs
0 2013-10-26 12:43:00 2014-12-15 00:04:00             9816  9947.35
1 2014-02-03 12:43:00 2015-03-25 00:04:00             9888  9947.35
2 2014-05-14 12:43:00 2015-07-03 00:04:00             9816  9947.35
```